# Python# Pandas Verwirrung

Tags: python

this is where the dataframe is spliteted. in the last line should come at Name None and at country Japan. how to build a filter so that if a country is to column country and if a name to column name

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


people = {
     "Name": ["john;italy", 'jorgen;USA', 'Japan'], 
}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(people)
df
df[['Name','country']] = df['Name'].str.split(';', expand=True)
df
```